# racadm - ERROR: Specified file <filename> does not exist

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to run `racadm` both in Windows Powershell using the official utility and on my Mac using [this Docker container](https://github.com/cacack/dockerfiles/tree/master/racadm). In both instances, I can pull the RAC details, so I know my login and password are valid, but when I try to perform an `sslkeyupload`, I get the following error:

`ERROR: Specified file file.pem does not exist.`

The permissions on the file, at least on my Mac, are wide open (`chmod 777`) and are in the same directory I'm trying to run the script in:

```
docker run stackbot/racadm -r 10.10.1.4 -u root -p calvin sslkeyupload -t 1 -f ./file.pem
```

Anyone see anything obvious I may be doing wrong?

Comment: @larsks Perfect. If you throw this in as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it. :) Thank you!

Comment: I've moved the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the command inside a Docker container. It has no visibility to your local filesystem unless you explicitly expose your directory inside the container using the -v command line option:

```
docker run -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD ...
```

The `-v` option creates a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), and the `-w` option sets the working directory.